# Find the shortest distance Destination Address

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have the following JSON pulled from this link [Click Here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=89706&destinations=94536%7C73301%7C61462&key=AIzaSyBQu1UgozO7yjQzYtvZkB05RI-5E6Qo5DU)

What I would like to do is write a function in PHP that returns the closest destination zip code to the origin address. So it should return 94536.

Been at it for about 4 hours and not having much luck with a format here :). Ty in advance.

This is what I have so far in a Code Igniter Function

```
<?php
```

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Location extends MX_Controller {

```
public function index()
{
    $json = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=89706&destinations=94536|73301|61462&key=AIzaSyBQu1UgozO7yjQzYtvZkB05RI-5E6Qo5DU');
    $jsondecoded = json_decode($json);

    //testing to get first zip code just to make sure we can get zip code only (Not needed here)
        $matches = [];
        preg_match("#.*?(\d+)#", json_decode($json, true)['destination_addresses'][0], $matches);
        echo $matches[1];

    // just a test to see that the complete json is there. (Not needed here just for testing)
    echo '<hr>';
        echo '<pre>';
            print_r($jsondecoded);
        echo '</pre>';
    echo '<hr>';

    // looping though elements tryign to order the distance text by closest first   (lost here but still testing)
    foreach ($jsondecoded->rows as $element) {
        echo '<pre>';
            print_r($element);
        echo '</pre>';
        echo '<hr>';
    }

    // I need to build a function that find the closest destination_addresses zip code and return it. So i would need to sort the rows->elements->distance->text / value by the closest adn then match that to correct destination_addresses

}
```

}

Comment: In which part your problem is? As I see, you need to decode json, find minimum distance's id in `elements`, then find zip code by regexp in element of `destination_addresses` with same id

Answer (score 1):

You just need decode the json let's say it will be in $json variable and use simple regex where `\d` represent digit

```
$json = ''; //your json from curl or any other way
$matches = [];

preg_match("#.*?(\d+)#", json_decode($json, true)['destination_addresses'][0], $matches);

echo $matches[1]; // your adress
```

Probably you will need add some checkings if the json response contain array keys etc.

[Working fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d846625641f8d3577900d1f316b0ddd64edbfacf)

Comment: i like the preg_match that is nice to see work, however that just echos the first destination_address.  I need to figure is find the closest destination_address from the origin_address giving. I will edit my question above to try to make that more clear.  TY